# Tensorflow estimator ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((?, 1) vs (?,))

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm classifying movie reviews as positive or negative using binary crossentropy. So, when I'm trying to wrap my keras model with tensorflow estimator, I get the error:

```
Tensorflow estimator ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((?, 1) vs (?,))
```

I'm using sigmoid activation as my last layer, guess I'm missing something trivial here. Any help?

```
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow as tf
print("Tensorflow {} loaded".format(tf.__version__))
import numpy as np

keras.__version__
from keras.datasets import imdb

(train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = imdb.load_data(num_words=10000)
def vectorize_sequences(sequences, dimension=10000):
    # Create an all-zero matrix of shape (len(sequences), dimension)
    results = np.zeros((len(sequences), dimension))
    for i, sequence in enumerate(sequences):
        results[i, sequence] = 1.  # set specific indices of results[i] to 1s
    return results.astype('float32')

# Our vectorized training data
x_train = vectorize_sequences(train_data)

# Our vectorized test data
x_test = vectorize_sequences(test_data)

# Our vectorized labels
y_train = np.asarray(train_labels).astype('float32')
y_test = np.asarray(test_labels).astype('float32')

x_val = x_train[:10000]
partial_x_train = x_train[10000:]
y_val = y_train[:10000]
partial_y_train = y_train[10000:]

model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', input_shape=(10000,), name='reviews'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
estimator_model = keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(keras_model=model)

def input_function(features,labels=None,shuffle=False,epochs=None,batch_size=None):
    input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
        x={"reviews_input": features},
        y=labels,
        shuffle=shuffle,
        num_epochs=epochs,
        batch_size=batch_size
    )
    return input_fn

estimator_model.train(input_fn=input_function(partial_x_train, partial_y_train, True,20,512))
score = estimator_model.evaluate(input_function(x_val, labels=y_val))
print(score)
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You should reshape your labels as 2d-tensor (the first dimension will be the batch dimension and the second the scalar label):

```
# Our vectorized labels
y_train = np.asarray(train_labels).astype('float32').reshape((-1,1))
y_test = np.asarray(test_labels).astype('float32').reshape((-1,1))
```

Answer (score 29):

If you're doing a binary classification, make sure that that your last Dense layer has just (None, 1) in its shape, not None, 2)

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid") # binary activation output
```

Comment: why? Isn't 2 right for binary?

Comment: Binary is 0 or 1. You only need one node to represent 0 or 1

Answer (score 15):

Check your network using model.summary()

You eventually need to thin down the network to have the same outputs as your classes.
For example, doing OCR for numbers needs and final output of Dense(10) (for numbers 0 to 9).

For example characterizing dogs vs. cats.  The final layer has to have two outputs (0-dog, 1-cat)

Comment: Your last sentence is only true if you use softmax + cross entropy. With sigmoid + binary cross entropy the final dense layer should have 1 node.

Comment: @kelkka you are right...I tried your suggestion (I m not the original author of this question) with a project and it definetely works... Thumb up!

Comment: @kelkka @Dave -- I tried `tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()` with `tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')` as the last layer but it shows an error of `ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 2) are incompatible`. But when I tried with 2 nodes, it can fit without error. 

What is the issue here?

Comment: Okay I got the solution. Need to use 'SpaseCategoricalCrossentropy()` if use `Softmax` for 2 nodes for last layer

Comment: @curiousguy it's been a while since I used TensorFlow, but I suspect your ValueError comes from how you've encoded the labels. If you use one-hot encode labels (e.g. [0, 1] for cat, [1,0] for dog), then you use CategoricalCrossentropy. If you don't and use labels like above and use 0 for cat and 1 for dog, then SparseCategoricalCrossentropy is correct.

Answer (score 12):

We can solve this problem by matching the output with the dimension of the label by adding a Flatten layer after the Dense layer:

```
model.add(Flatten())
```

or by adding:

```
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
```

[See this GitHub issue for full details](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/issues/157)

Answer (score 6):

If you're doing binary cross-entropy, then your dataset probably has 2 classes and the error is coming because your label vectors (both in testing and training) have the form [0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,...]. To one-hot encode binary labels, the following function can be used: `Labels = tf.one_hot(Labels, depth=2)`

Answer (score 0):

In the last layer, instead of one output, you should use two outputs:

```
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Comment: Why should the poster use two outputs? Your answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76246779/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

you must add:

```
model.add(layers.Flatten())
```

or:

```
model.add(layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())
```

Comment: This is already mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69363287/6045800)