# "ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 32) are incompatible" when training image classification network in TensorFlow using categorical_crossentropy

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to train a machine learning model to classify images, but I am getting some issues when I attempt to use the categorical_crossentropy loss function.

Here is the code that I am using to generate my model.

```
import numpy as np
import os
import PIL
import PIL.Image
import tensorflow as tf
import pathlib
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import callbacks 
from tensorflow import keras
from datetime import datetime
import tensorboard

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #This first section mostly follows the tutorial at https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification
    data_dir = "img_directories"
    image_count = len(list(glob.glob(f'{data_dir}/*/*.png')))
    print(image_count)

    batch_size = 128
    img_height = 100 
    img_width = 100

    #Set up training data
    val_split = 0.2

    train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    validation_split=val_split,
    subset="training",
    seed=123,
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size)

    #Set up testing data
    val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    validation_split=val_split,
    subset="validation",
    seed=123,
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size, 
    color_mode='rgb')

    class_names = train_ds.class_names
    print(class_names)

    num_classes = len(train_ds.class_names)

    #   Normalize data
    normalization_layer = layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255)
    normalized_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))
    image_batch, labels_batch = next(iter(normalized_ds))

    #Set up model

    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    # model.add(layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling((1./255),input_shape=(100, 100, 3)))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu',input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3)))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (5,5)))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3)))
    model.add(layers.Dense(64))
    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
    
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])


    model.summary()

    earlystopping = callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor ="val_loss",  
                                        mode ="min", patience = 7,  
                                        restore_best_weights = True) 


    history=model.fit(
    normalized_ds,
    validation_data=val_ds,
    epochs=100,
    callbacks=[earlystopping]
    )
```

Setting the loss function to `categorical_crossentropy` gives me the following errors:

```
    ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 32) are incompatible
```

Where 32 is the number of classes in my dataset that I have, therefore it is having issues with my output layer.

However, it does not appear to have issues when I try to run it with `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`

How do I make it work with `categorical_crossentropy` because I have so few classes?

Edit:

I have tried something like this, but I am still getting errors similar to the original.

```
    val_imgs, val_labels = next(iter(val_ds))
    val_labels_one_hot=tf.one_hot(labels_batch,num_classes)

    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])


    model.summary()

    earlystopping = callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor ="val_loss",  
                                        mode ="min", patience = 7,  
                                        restore_best_weights = True) 

    history=model.fit(
    train_ds,
    validation_data=[val_imgs,val_labels_one_hot],
    epochs=100,
    callbacks=[earlystopping]
    )
```

Comment: Are your labels one-hot encoded? Please post a sample. Even better, adapt the tutorial keeping the data used therein to create a [mcve].

Comment: Please check this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/326065/cross-entropy-vs-sparse-cross-entropy-when-to-use-one-over-the-other). You just need to one hot encode your labels.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 2) are incompatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61742556/valueerror-shapes-none-1-and-none-2-are-incompatible)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what one-hot encoding is because I have just started using TensorFlow. Here is a link to the dataset I am using https://github.com/ivyjsgit/HOMUS-Bitmap . It gets the labels from the names of the folders through the tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory.

Comment: @IvyJackson see the link in my answer. The vector has num_classes entries. One vector per sample. Every index encodes a class. If position N is 1 (and the rest 0), then this encodes class N.

Comment: You should read the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image_dataset_from_directory) for `image_dataset_from_directory`, the argument `label_mode` specifically.

Comment: @Nicolas Gervais That fixed the issue! Now to debug the much larger loss values under the new loss function.

Answer (score 1):

`sparse_categorical_crossentropy` ([documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/SparseCategoricalCrossentropy)) assumes integers whereas `categorical_crossentropy` ([documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalCrossentropy)) assumes one-hot encoding vectors. You can use both but `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` works because you're providing each label with shape `(None, 1)`.

In summary, if you want to use `categorical_crossentropy`, you'll need to convert your current target tensor to [one-hot encodings](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/one_hot) (which will then be used by the final softmax layer).

Comment: I have looked at the documentation, but I'm still not quite sure that I understand how to convert my training dataset, which is stored as a BatchDataset into a one-hot encoded tensor.

Comment: I think I did something to add one-hot encoding, but either I didn't implement it correctly, or it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: I hit this issue when using batch dataset and categorial cross entropy for a classification problem with multiple labels. Changing to sparse_categorical_crossentropy fixed it. Alternatively, using one-hot encoding for the labels would help train with categorial cross entropy.