# why am I getting error in transfer learning?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning, pre-trained-model

**I am training a model for Optical Character Recognition of Gujarati Language. The input image is a character image. I have taken 37 classes. Total training images are 22200 (600 per class) and testing images are 5920 (160 per class). My input images are 32x32**

**Below is my code:**

```
model = tf.keras.applications.DenseNet121(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', pooling='max')
base_inputs = model.layers[0].input
base_outputs = model.layers[-1].output # NOTICE -1 not -2
prefinal_outputs = layers.Dense(1024)(base_outputs)
final_outputs = layers.Dense(37)(prefinal_outputs)
new_model = keras.Model(inputs=base_inputs, outputs=base_outputs)
    
    from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
    
    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
                                       shear_range=0.2,
                                       zoom_range=0.2,
                                       
                                       
                                       horizontal_flip=False)
    
    test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip = False)
    
    training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('C:/Users/shweta/Desktop/characters/train',
                                                     target_size = (32, 32),
                                                     batch_size = 64,
                                                     class_mode = 'categorical')
    
    test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('C:/Users/shweta/Desktop/characters/test',
                                                target_size = (32, 32),
                                                batch_size = 64,
                                                class_mode = 'categorical')
    
    new_model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
    
    new_model.fit_generator(training_set,
                            
                             epochs = 25,
                             validation_data = test_set, shuffle=True)
    new_model.save('alphanumeric.mod')
```

**I am getting following output:**

[image: Output of code]

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: see my amended answer. I think you were selecting the wrong layer as the output

Comment: Hey! I tried your amended code by mentioning input shape. But still getting the same error!!

Comment: I am confused. What should be the exact line of code?!!!

Comment: see amended answer

Comment: OK! Understood the code. But accuracy saturated at 0.027. l have added my output in the question. have a look!

Comment: not sure what is wrong. Looks like it is not training at all. Would have to see data set to figure out what is going on. IF you use kaggle post it there and put the link in a comment

Comment: Here's the dataset  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DrdpH9J6Nc8QXl_hbi2wH_1SIpLidxD9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: UGH forgot to include code to compile the model. See  amended answer

Comment: Yes I have included that in my code..!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, very well written code.
These are some of the things, I have noticed while I was going through the code and tf,keras docs.

I would like to ask what kind of labels have you got beacuse you know categorical_crossentropy expects ONE HOT CODED labels.([Check this](https://keras.io/api/losses/probabilistic_losses/#categoricalcrossentropy-class)).So, if your labels are integers, use [sparsecategoricalentropy](https://keras.io/api/losses/probabilistic_losses/#sparsecategoricalcrossentropy-function).

Similar issue
There was [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61742556/valueerror-shapes-none-1-and-none-2-are-incompatible) where someone was trying to classsify into 2 and used categorical instead of binary crossentropy. If you want to look at.

Cheers
Let me know how it goes!

PS: @gerry made a very good point and if labels are One hot encoded use categoricalcrossentropy!

Comment: The labels are the names of the class directories and are categorical still i am facing this error!!!The error deals with the second last layer i guess with 1024 units!

Comment: I think you took last but one layer. Have a look at thje pic in this link https://www.kaggle.com/pytorch/densenet121. change output layer to [-1] maybe also do the layers of densenet121 wraparound so u can use[-neg] index? let me know how it goes

Comment: what do u mean by DenseNet121 wraparound? [-1] means that I am considering the last layer of DenseNet121. and [-2] means second last layer if I am not wrong.

Comment: Thats right.I have just seen ur custom prefinal layer.Also try @jerry's new code which includes changing index to -1. I believe the error lies around final and prefinal. so i would recommend you to use another pretrained model and try it. you might as well findout yourself. I could try on my PC but havent got the dataset!

Comment: I can send u my dataset in zip file if u can try the code!

Comment: sure if u a drive link lmk

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DrdpH9J6Nc8QXl_hbi2wH_1SIpLidxD9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for the link I have just seen. let me look into it

Comment: Okay! Do revert back to me after u go through!

Comment: I did go through the code. no matter WHAT I DO. It wont learn. I guess the DATASET is ripped. I seriously think the pictures in the dataset have too much noise or there is something wrong about it. Do you know anyone actually making it work with this dataset. Also ImageDataGen makes this go round and round and edit it. I kinda honestly believe it is the Dataset at this point. try getting other dataset and try train_test_split() and actually make one dataset with python maybe. Sorry for getting back late!.

Answer (score 0):

The code should be:

```
model = tf.keras.applications.DenseNet121(include_top=False, weights='imagenet, pooling='max', input_shape=(32,32,3))
base_outputs = model.layers[-1].output 
prefinal_outputs = layers.Dense(1024)(base_outputs)
final_outputs = layers.Dense(37)(prefinal_outputs)
new_model = keras.Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=final_outputs)
new_model.compile(Adam(), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Also you should use model.fit in the future. Model.fit can now work with generators and model.fit_generator will be depreciate in future versions of tensorflow. I ran against your dataset and got accurate results in about 10 epochs.  Here is some additional advice. It is best to use and adjustable learning rate. The keras callback ReduceLROnPlateau makes this easy to do. Documentation is [here.](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/reduce_lr_on_plateau/) Set it to monitor the validation loss. My use is shown below.

```
lr_adjust=tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau( monitor="val_loss", factor=0.5, patience=1, verbose=1, mode="auto",
        min_delta=0.00001,  cooldown=0,  min_lr=0)
```

Also I recommend using the callback ModelCheckpoint. Documentation is [here.](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/model_checkpoint/) Set it up to monitor validation loss and it will save the weights that achieved the lowest validation loss. My implementation is shown below.

```
sav_loc=r'c:\Temp' # set this to the path where you want to save the weights
checkpoint=tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=save_loc, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True,
        save_weights_only=True, mode='auto', save_freq='epoch', options=None)
callbacks=[checkpoint, lr_adjust]
```

In model.fit include callbacks=callbacks. When training is completed you want to load these saved weights into the model, then save the model. You can use the saved model to make predictions. Code is below.

```
model.load_weights(save_loc)  
model.save(save_loc)
```

Comment: Hey ! I ran this code and got the expected output. So there are no discrepancies in the train and test folders. So what could be the other reason for getting the above posted error?!

Comment: I ran your edited code but getting an error. I have edited the question and the error which I got. Please have a look!!!