# tensorflow.keras program returns same predictions everytime

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

error:

```
 Using TensorFlow backend.
    C:\anaconda\envs\yoyeo2012\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py:136: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
      return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order, subok=True)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/심현규/PycharmProjects/yoyeo2012/main.py", line 86, in <module>
        model.load_weights(hdf5_file)
      File "C:\anaconda\envs\yoyeo2012\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 492, in load_wrapper
        return load_function(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\anaconda\envs\yoyeo2012\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 1230, in load_weights
        f, self.layers, reshape=reshape)
      File "C:\anaconda\envs\yoyeo2012\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 1237, in load_weights_from_hdf5_group
        K.batch_set_value(weight_value_tuples)
      File "C:\anaconda\envs\yoyeo2012\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 2960, in batch_set_value
        tf_keras_backend.batch_set_value(tuples)
      File "C:\anaconda\envs\yoyeo2012\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\backend.py", line 3323, in batch_set_value
        x.assign(np.asarray(value, dtype=dtype(x)))
      File "C:\anaconda\envs\yoyeo2012\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py", line 819, in assign
        self._shape.assert_is_compatible_with(value_tensor.shape)
      File "C:\anaconda\envs\yoyeo2012\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\tensor_shape.py", line 1110, in assert_is_compatible_with
        raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))
    ValueError: Shapes (512, 1) and (512, 2) are incompatible
```

I'm trying to make my first tensorflow model defining which of the picture is pear or apple, however I have some issues. It seems that it makes the train correctly, but when it does a prediction it just returns (almost) always the same value and the loss is higher than its accuracy.I need some help !,  Here's the code:

```
import os
import glob
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, Dense, Flatten, Activation
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] ='2'

img_path = {
    'C:/pear/': '배', # pear
    'C:/apple/': '사과' #apple
}

img_dir = 'C:/'
categories = ['apple', 'pear']
nclasses = len(categories)

img_w = 64
img_h = 64

pixels = img_w * 3 * img_h
x = []
y = []

for i, cat in enumerate(categories): #
    label = [0 for i in range(nclasses)]
    label[i] = 1

    r_dir = img_dir + cat + '/'
    files = glob.glob(r_dir + '/*.jpg')

    for c, f in enumerate(files):
        img = Image.open(f)
        img = img.convert('RGB')
        img = img.resize((img_w, img_h))
        data = np.asarray(img)

        x.append(data)
        y.append(label)

x= np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = \
    train_test_split(x, y)
xy = (x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test)

np.save('C:train.npy',xy)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = np.load('train.npy',allow_pickle=True)

x_train = x_train.astype('float') / 256
x_test = x_test.astype('float') /256


model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=x_train.shape[1:], padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

# 전결합층
model.add(Flatten())    # 벡터형태로 reshape
model.add(Dense(512))   # 출력
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
# 모델 구축하기
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])

hdf5_file = "7obj-model.hdf5"
if os.path.exists(hdf5_file):
    model.load_weights(hdf5_file)
else:
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, nb_epoch=10)
    model.save_weights(hdf5_file)

score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print('loss = ', score[0])
print('accuracy = ', score[1])

img_list = ['apple.jpg', 'apple.jpg', 'pear.jpg', 'pear1.jpg', 'pear2.jpg', 'pear3.jpg', 'pear4.jpg'] # test pictures
for test_image in img_list:
    # 이미지 resize
    img = Image.open(test_image)
    img = img.convert("RGB")
    img = img.resize((64,64))
    data = np.asarray(img)
    X = np.array(data)
    X = X.astype("float") / 256
    X = X.reshape(-1, 64, 64,3)
    # 예측
    pred = model.predict(X)
    result = [np.argmax(value) for value in pred]
    print('New data category : ',categories[result[0]]) # return prediction
```

and here comes the training:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
C:\anaconda\envs\yoyeo2012\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py:136: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
  return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order, subok=True)

  32/2861 [..............................] - ETA: 23s
  96/2861 [>.............................] - ETA: 10s
 128/2861 [>.............................] - ETA: 9s 
 160/2861 [>.............................] - ETA: 8s
 192/2861 [=>............................] - ETA: 7s
 224/2861 [=>............................] - ETA: 7s
 256/2861 [=>............................] - ETA: 6s
 288/2861 [==>...........................] - ETA: 6s
 320/2861 [==>...........................] - ETA: 6s
 352/2861 [==>...........................] - ETA: 5s
 384/2861 [===>..........................] - ETA: 5s
 416/2861 [===>..........................] - ETA: 5s
 448/2861 [===>..........................] - ETA: 5s
 480/2861 [====>.........................] - ETA: 5s
 512/2861 [====>.........................] - ETA: 5s
 544/2861 [====>.........................] - ETA: 4s
 576/2861 [=====>........................] - ETA: 4s
 608/2861 [=====>........................] - ETA: 4s
 640/2861 [=====>........................] - ETA: 4s
 672/2861 [======>.......................] - ETA: 4s
 704/2861 [======>.......................] - ETA: 4s
 736/2861 [======>.......................] - ETA: 4s
 768/2861 [=======>......................] - ETA: 4s
 800/2861 [=======>......................] - ETA: 4s
 832/2861 [=======>......................] - ETA: 4s
 864/2861 [========>.....................] - ETA: 4s
 896/2861 [========>.....................] - ETA: 3s
 928/2861 [========>.....................] - ETA: 3s
 960/2861 [=========>....................] - ETA: 3s
 992/2861 [=========>....................] - ETA: 3s
1024/2861 [=========>....................] - ETA: 3s
1056/2861 [==========>...................] - ETA: 3s
1088/2861 [==========>...................] - ETA: 3s
1120/2861 [==========>...................] - ETA: 3s
1152/2861 [===========>..................] - ETA: 3s
1184/2861 [===========>..................] - ETA: 3s
1216/2861 [===========>..................] - ETA: 3s
1248/2861 [============>.................] - ETA: 3s
1280/2861 [============>.................] - ETA: 3s
1312/2861 [============>.................] - ETA: 2s
1344/2861 [=============>................] - ETA: 2s
1376/2861 [=============>................] - ETA: 2s
1408/2861 [=============>................] - ETA: 2s
1440/2861 [==============>...............] - ETA: 2s
1472/2861 [==============>...............] - ETA: 2s
1504/2861 [==============>...............] - ETA: 2s
1536/2861 [===============>..............] - ETA: 2s
1568/2861 [===============>..............] - ETA: 2s
1600/2861 [===============>..............] - ETA: 2s
1632/2861 [================>.............] - ETA: 2s
1664/2861 [================>.............] - ETA: 2s
1696/2861 [================>.............] - ETA: 2s
1728/2861 [=================>............] - ETA: 2s
1760/2861 [=================>............] - ETA: 2s
1792/2861 [=================>............] - ETA: 2s
1824/2861 [==================>...........] - ETA: 1s
1856/2861 [==================>...........] - ETA: 1s
1888/2861 [==================>...........] - ETA: 1s
1920/2861 [===================>..........] - ETA: 1s
1952/2861 [===================>..........] - ETA: 1s
1984/2861 [===================>..........] - ETA: 1s
2016/2861 [====================>.........] - ETA: 1s
2048/2861 [====================>.........] - ETA: 1s
2080/2861 [====================>.........] - ETA: 1s
2112/2861 [=====================>........] - ETA: 1s
2144/2861 [=====================>........] - ETA: 1s
2176/2861 [=====================>........] - ETA: 1s
2208/2861 [======================>.......] - ETA: 1s
2240/2861 [======================>.......] - ETA: 1s
2272/2861 [======================>.......] - ETA: 1s
2304/2861 [=======================>......] - ETA: 1s
2336/2861 [=======================>......] - ETA: 0s
2368/2861 [=======================>......] - ETA: 0s
2400/2861 [========================>.....] - ETA: 0s
2432/2861 [========================>.....] - ETA: 0s
2464/2861 [========================>.....] - ETA: 0s
2496/2861 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s
2528/2861 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s
2560/2861 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s
2592/2861 [==========================>...] - ETA: 0s
2624/2861 [==========================>...] - ETA: 0s
2656/2861 [==========================>...] - ETA: 0s
2688/2861 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s
2720/2861 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s
2752/2861 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s
2784/2861 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s
2816/2861 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s
2848/2861 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s
2861/2861 [==============================] - 5s 2ms/step
loss =  0.712629729844773
accuracy =  0.5686822533607483
New data category :  apple
New data category :  apple
New data category :  apple
New data category :  apple
New data category :  apple
New data category :  apple
New data category :  apple

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Can you try to add `sigmoid` instead of `softmax` activation in the last layer and modify compile code block as `model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'Adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])`?

Comment: i havent tried it yet , but what's the difference between those?

Comment: Can you try to change `model.add(Dense(nclasses))` to `model.add(Dense(1))` apart from above modifications and let us know? Here you are trying to recognize 2 classes hence you should try *binary_crossentropy* as loss, in case of more than 2 classes where you can try with *categorical_crossentropy*.

Comment: I did what you've said and I 've got error I posted on the top . can you check what 's wrong?

Comment: Please can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61747496/14290681).Hope this helps you. If the issue is still persists, please can you share Colab file with the latest code which you have tried, so that we can help you.

Comment: I edited to my last code can you check it ? I'm really sorry for multiple questions

Comment: @ 심현규, Can you please share your working colab file? It helps to fix your issue quickly.