# ValueError: in user code:.......ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 5) are incompatible

Tags: deep-learning, word2vec, text-classification, word-embedding, multiclass-classification

```
nn_model = Sequential([
    Embedding(input_dim=max_features, input_length=max_len, output_dim=embedding_dims),
    GlobalMaxPool1D(),
    Dense(50, activation = 'relu'),
    Dropout(0.2),
    Dense(5, activation = 'softmax')
])
```

............................

```
def mean_pred(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(y_pred)

nn_model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=Adam(0.01), metrics=['accuracy', mean_pred, fmeasure, precision, auroc, recall])
```

[image]

.....................................
When I feed the data to NN model I got the above error, so please how can i resolve it.

```
nn_model_fit = nn_model.fit(X_tra, y_tra, batch_size=batch_size2, epochs=num_epochs, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), callbacks=[early])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 2) are incompatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61742556/valueerror-shapes-none-1-and-none-2-are-incompatible)

Comment: I tried this "sparse_categorical_crossentropy"  but still have error, so now i don't know how to solve it.

Comment: which error are you obtaining now?

Comment: ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 5) are incompatible.... this one bro