# Using the saved weights of one mode for training new deep model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am new to tensorflow. I am trying to use VGG16 model for image classification by training it onto a deepweeds dataset available on the tensorflow dataset that contains 9 classes in it. After training the model, I am saving its weights in .h5 extension. Now, I am trying to use the saved weights as a default weight for training the vgg16 model on new dataset that contain three classes.
[Here is the sample code that I am using to train on new dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qO2s4.png)

[But everytime, I get some errors such as:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKvh0.png)

Will appreciate your help and suggestions

Comment: have you tried the solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48851558/tensorflow-estimator-valueerror-logits-and-labels-must-have-the-same-shape)?

Comment: Yes, I tried to thin down the last layer to the required amount of number of classes