# ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 256, 256, 1) vs (None,))

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to train my cnn model using unet architecture for binary classification of eggs however when I get to the block for training the model,
I have this code that is generating error about the same shape:

```
# Define U-Net model for binary classification
def unet_binary(input_shape=(256, 256, 3)):
    inputs = Input(input_shape)
    
    # Encoder
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
    
    conv2 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool1)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
    
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool2)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)
    
    # Decoder
    up1 = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(pool3)
    merge1 = concatenate([conv3, up1], axis=3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(merge1)
    
    up2 = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv4)
    merge2 = concatenate([conv2, up2], axis=3)
    conv5 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(merge2)
    
    up3 = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv5)
    merge3 = concatenate([conv1, up3], axis=3)
    conv6 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(merge3)
    
    # Classification layer
    outputs = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid')(conv6)
    
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    return model
# Create the model
model = unet_binary()

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Print model summary
model.summary()

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), epochs=10, batch_size=16)
```

However while raining the first epoch I get the error below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[23], line 1
----> 1 history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), epochs=10, batch_size=16)

File C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filebd9f_n7s.py:15, in outer_factory.<locals>.inner_factory.<locals>.tf__train_function(iterator)
     13 try:
     14     do_return = True
---> 15     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16 except:
     17     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1401, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1384, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1373, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1151, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1209, in compute_loss
        return self.compiled_loss(
    File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\compile_utils.py", line 277, in __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\src\losses.py", line 143, in __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\src\losses.py", line 270, in call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\src\losses.py", line 2532, in binary_crossentropy
        backend.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits),
    File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\src\backend.py", line 5822, in binary_crossentropy
        return tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(

    ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 256, 256, 1) vs (None,)).
```

I've shared my code here at [Codeshare](https://codeshare.io/644xj0) so you could look up my code for better context. Can you help me understand whats the problem? Thank you!

I have tried reshaping my labels as 2d-tensor as described in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48851558/tensorflow-estimator-valueerror-logits-and-labels-must-have-the-same-shape) but it still returned the same error. I want to be able to train my model so using unet for binary classification.

Answer (score 0):

U-Net architectures are used for binary segmentation, in which the spatial dimensions (height and width) of the output is the same as the input.

Could you share the shape of y_train? I think that your output is of size (256x256x1) but your network's output is (1x1)

Comment: Hi these are the shapes 
print(X_train.shape,X_val.shape,X_test.shape)
print("---------------")
print(y_train.shape,y_val.shape,y_test.shape) 

(1063, 256, 256, 3) (228, 256, 256, 3) (227, 256, 256, 3)
---------------
(1063,) (228,) (227,)

Comment: Ok. The problem is in your network design. Actually, the output of your network is (256x256x1). In the encoding path, your decrease the size of your input, but in the decoding path, you reconstruct it. If your want your network to give only 1 output, don't use upsampling layers. Exclude the decoding path and add Dense layers, instead.

Comment: Thanks for the added knowledge, however isn't excluding the decoding path and adding dense layers would mean that it no longer is a unet architecture? I wanted to use uNet for this binary classification. So I should convert my images to grayscale? What would you recommend?

Comment: You can't use U-net for a regular binary classification. As I mentioned, it is used for segmentation, which is a pixel-wise classification.